# What is the iesiest way to transform an SVG image using an arbitrary function (x,y) --> (x'(x,y),y'(x,y))?

Tags: svg

What is the easiest way to transform the (x,y) coordinates of an SVG image in the following way:

```
x --> x'(x,y)
y --> y'(x,y)
```

Example:

```
x --> x^2+y^2
y --> sinx + cosy
```

The method can either modify the original SVG file or produce a new SVG file containing the modified SVG image.

Comment: (translate)(rotate) matrix transforms?  what exactly do you mean by "easiest way" ?  Easiest way for the programmer to finish up fast and have a beer? Easiest way for the CPU to process the transform?  Seems like you are asking for an opinion. What have you tried?  (I'm assuming you are writing a game / other animation and moving an svg object around the screen, etc... Is that correct?)

Comment: "Easiest way for the programmer to finish up fast and have a beer?" Yes. (I'm assuming you are writing a game / other animation and moving an svg object around the screen, etc... Is that correct?) No, actually I am trying to change an SVG map projection from Sinusoidal to Equirectangular.

Comment: Sorry,  that sounds like a homework assignment.  If it were me, I'd start here...http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/geometry/geo-tran.html and then find a nice matrix library for your language of choice.

Comment: whoa... projection.. are you talking about just the center point on the SVG or each and every (x, y) point contained within?  (note, you've not mentioned your language of choice, but I'm assuming this gets the JavaScript tag?)  (and personally I like canvas over SVG for this one)

Comment: It's not a homework assignment. The problem is not with the mathematical theory behind the transform, the problem is with the application of said theory. In other words, I don't know how I can program the transformation given an SVG image file.

Comment: Why SVG? (Its handy if you need clickable items, or you've got sprites all made up, or you need to scale up / down and maintain awesome beauty)  In simple words SVG is concerned with the shape of things.  Canvas is concerned with Pixels.  If its just an image you are starting with, I'd sure look at using Canvas instead.  I think this would be an easier task in Canvas, but would have to try it.

Comment: Each and every (x,y) point in the SVG, yes. The language is pretty much immaterial, as long as I can use it to transform the SVG image.

Comment: It's already in SVG format, and for a number of reasons I can't turn it into Canvas.

Comment: I've been trying to find the revolved image captcha from http://www.minteye.com/ to understand how that worked.   It was way cool. They took an image and twisted it up from the center.  You'd use a slider to make it normal again before you could submit on the site. I don't see it at there anymore.   I've also just been playing around with SVG and transform="matrix(...)" at jsfiddle and getting nowhere fast.  Have you pulled a jsfiddle yet?  that really helps us help you...

Answer (score 0):

Remember that SVG includes the following functions:

- translate()
- rotate()
- scale()
- skew()
- matrix()

I initially thought you could use the matrix transformation function that is available to the SVG system.  Because that matrix is static, I'm not positive you will get what you are after.  A lot depends on what the transform matrix looks like.

Here's a sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lofzvd7h/1/).

```
<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="300" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <image x="20" y="20" width="300" height="250" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/Cow_female_black_white.jpg" />
</svg>

<h2>A skew transformation along the y-axis</h2>

<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="300" height="400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <image x="20" y="20" width="300" height="250" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0c/Cow_female_black_white.jpg" 
    transform="matrix(1,.5,0,1,0,0)" />
</svg>
```

Have you looked at the D3.js library for your projection stuff?  D3 uses SVG elements, and they've got some pretty good tools. I see folks writing additional tools for that as well.  Have you seen the [geo projections project for D3 at Github](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections)?  I do see d3.geo.equirectangular option there.  Perhaps that will get you to beer quickly?

I do know you can do much more involved stuff using Canvas. You'd have to convert your SVG image over to Canvas, but that is do-able.  Check out this [awesome tutorial](http://geekofficedog.blogspot.com/2013/04/hello-swirl-swirl-effect-tutorial-in.html) for swirling an image dynamically, in canvas.

Comment: So is there any way to perform the kind of transformations you can with Canvas with SVGs? I don't think that D3 is what I'm looking for because I want the functions to be arbitrary, not pre-set.

Comment: Sure.  The D3 plug ins I've listed above are open source, all the code is in github.  Look at the code, figure out how it works, move it along.  First I'd try playing with the transform matrices of your choice, see if you can get them to work.  Remember I haven't seen your raw starting code in your jsfiddle presentation.  You haven't explained very well what you are trying to convert.  Is the conversion done once and then displayed, or is a dynamic conversion, like the canvas tutorial I've linked above?